# Error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement seleniumwire on windows server 2022

Tags: python, windows, selenium, seleniumwire

i  m new devolaper at python , wanted to user seleniumwire in my window 11

i install the code "pip install seleniumwire"  getting this error  "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement seleniumwire"

pls help on this

Answer (score -1):

Try this insted
Pip install --user seleniumwire

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Code-only answers may be downvoted.